# _onLocationFound doesn't work in leaflet.locationcontrol

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using leaflet.locatecontrol to get users' location in the map but _onLocationFound doesn't work.
here is my map component

```
      <Map
        ref={ref}
        center={initialState ? initialState.center : DEFAULT_CENTER}
        zoom={initialState ? initialState.zoom : 5}
        maxZoom={18}
        onMove={(e) => {
          onMapMove(e);
        }}
      >
        <TileLayer
          url={`${settings.getConfig().MAP_TILE_URL}${
            settings.getConfig().MAP_X_API_KEY
          }`}
          attribution={settings.getConfig().MAP_ATTRIBUTION}
        />
        {marker && (
          <Marker
            position={marker}
            icon={L.icon({
              iconUrl: "https://webstockreview.net/images/map-icon-png-6.png",

              iconSize: [25, 30], // size of the icon
              iconAnchor: [13, 36], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            })}
          />
        )}
        <LocateControl options={locateOptions} />

      </Map>
```

and this is the options I'm passing to LocateControl

```
  position: "bottomright",
  icon: "map-location-icon",
  strings: {
    title: "my location",
  },
  onLocationError: function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log("Location access denied.");
  },
  _onLocationFound: function (e) {
    console.log("event", e);
  },

  onActivate: () => {}, // callback before engine starts retrieving locations
}
```

and LocateControl is a simple component I implemented to separate the logic and here is its code:

```
import { withLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import Locate from "leaflet.locatecontrol";

class LocateControl extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { options, startDirectly } = this.props;
    const { map } = this.props.leaflet;

    const lc = new Locate(options);

    lc.addTo(map);

    if (startDirectly) {
      // request location update and set location
      lc.start();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default withLeaflet(LocateControl);
```

my problem is that I want to save the location when it's found but _onLocationFound function won't be triggered even though the location is updated in the map and I can't find out what am I missing out because even in the documentation the function is simply past to locateControl
[Here is the link to the source code of the package](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol/blob/gh-pages/src/L.Control.Locate.js)

I would be thankful if anyone could give me a hint

Answer (score 2):

You're passing an *option* named `_onLocationFound` which is **not** on the [list of supported options for Leaflet.LocateControl](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol#possible-options).

You probably did so because you looked at the code for Leaflet.LocateControl and confused the `onLocationError` *option* with the `_onLocationError` *method*, without noticing that the `_onLocationError` *method* explicitly calls its namesake *option* [here](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol/blob/8ebc5ca11e532cd2aa2ec6cf2b6e7343e7635c2b/src/L.Control.Locate.js#L724)...

```
    _onLocationError: function(err) {
        /* snip */
        this.options.onLocationError(err, this);
    },
```

...but you failed to realize that there is no `onLocationFound` option *at all*, and that the internal `_onLocationFound` *method* does not call any user-provided callback *at all*.

Instead, do it [the documented way](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol#events): Leverage the `locationfound` *event* on the map.